# Laravel | How to use Pivot table with Relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a question about the relationship. I have an activity model and controller. I guess I searched a lot, I find an attached method for this. But idk how to use it.

I have an activity table like this:

```
Schema::create('activities', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->string('company_name');
        $table->string('price');
        $table->string('description');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

And another table is activity_asset like this:

```
Schema::create('activity_asset', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreignId('activity_id')->constrained();
        $table->string('image')->nullable();
        $table->string('video')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Now I don't know how to relate these two tables. What do I want to do?
•

1. I have a form blade. The inputs
   title,company_name,price,description, video input, file input. (http://prntscr.com/10nyfd1 )
2. When I create a new activity (title, company_name, price, description)
   I want to add to video and image URL to add the activity_asset table
   with activity id.

**Short summary**: When I create a new activity, how to add other fields add to the activity_asset table with activity_id.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are they one-to-one realtionship? https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one

Comment: The 1 activity have to many activity_asset and 1 activity_asset have just one activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

First, create an activity.

```
$activity =  new Activity;
$activity->title = $request->title;
$activity->company_name = $request->company_name;
$activity->price = $request->price;
$activity->description = $request->description;
$activity->save();
```

```
foreach ($request->image as $key => $value) {
    $image[] = array(
        'activity_id'         => $activity->id,
        'image'             => $value,
    );
}
ActivityAsset::insert($image);
```

```
foreach ($request->video as $key => $value) {
    $video[] = array(
        'activity_id'         => $activity->id,
        'video'             => $value,
    );
}
ActivityAsset::insert($video);
```

Comment: Thanks for all helps!! That's exactly work for me :) of course i customize some field. Thanks a lot again.

Answer (score 0):

Pivot tables are used when having many-to-many relationships. But for your case, you have a One-to-many relationship. And don't need a pivot table.

A typical example of a many-to-many relationship is Article & Tags. Where 1 article can have many tags and 1 tag can belong to many articles.

But your example is one-to-many relationship. Where 1 activity can have many activity_asset and 1 activity_asset can one activity. in this case you do not need a pivot table.

Comment: That's right. So what's the next for me? Frankly i am confused. OK, tables are not pivoted, but how do I do this? I need to create a new model for activity_asset ?

Comment: You get all the data when you submit the form? if yes, then I will send you the code.

Comment: Yes my form is all data like that: https://prnt.sc/10nyfd1 . I mean when i create new activity , i want to image and video url add to activity_asset table with activity_id.

Comment: You can try above code :- https://stackoverflow.com/a/66670403/12213896

Comment: I'am trying right now. I let you know if that work, but thanks a lot for all help :) .

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you

```
public function method()
{
    $activity = Activity::find(1);

    $asset = $activity->assets()->create([
       'image' => 'url',
       'video' => 'url',
    ]);
}
```

in your activity model :

```
public function assets()
{
   return $this->hasMany('activity_asset', 'activity_id');
}
```